# Time tracking similar to Paymo Plus on Debian

Tags: debian, logging, time-management

- PaymoPlus is free (closed source but no fees)
- PaymoPlus sits in my System Tray all day, and records every window/tab I open

I would like to know if a similar app exists for Debian. Paymo for Windows/Mac has the additional sweet feature of being able to drag and drop working windows/tabs and the time spent into the tasks, but one can live without this.  I would at least need to know which tasks got how much time in a 'sum total' calculation so I can enter that time into my Paymo reporting.

Any ideas? Paymo does have a desktop widget for Linux but it is a dumb (non-sentient) manual time entry tool, not like Paymo Plus automatically recording everything being done.